# Query of a Query, then Query again to calculate

Tags: ms-access

I have a crosstab query (query1) which works fine... I'd like to use a Dlookup function in it but it seems not to understand the fields. So I have created select query on that crosstab (Query2) and it works OK.

I would then like to add other calculated fields based on the lookup values so I create another query based on query2 (say Query 3), which is the final one on which I base the report

Qn, Is it acceptable and functional or am I going too deep into the queries?
What are the alternatives?

[Working with access 2010]

Comment: If it works (=results are as expected) at reasonable speed, it is acceptable.

Comment: I usually find that basing a query on a crosstab doesn't work well.  Can you rewrite Query2 to use the source data for the crosstab directly, rather than the results of the crosstab?  That may also facilitate your use of DLookup

Comment: Thanks for the comments.@DonGeorge, that would defeat my purpose of the crosstab... I need to visualize the query that way and report it the same way... Otherwise I wouldn't know how to create the report